# Visual Studio Code : Restrict Intellisense to given typings file

Tags: intellisense, visual-studio-code

We have developed a javascript based DSL for our internal testing tool and planning to use Visual Studio Code as a preferred editor to develop the test scripts.

We developed the typings file to support intellisense for our DSL and it's working fine after configuring it using jsconfig.json.

However when I enter Ctrl+Space in blank javascript file (the file has been saved with .js extension), I see lot other intellisense suggestions along with our DSL. Please check the screen-shot,

[image: VS Code intellisense]

I have marked the appropriate suggestions with red-border box.

I would like VS Code to show / restrict the intellisense suggestions only to my typings file and basic javascript language (ES6).

Upon searching the file system I found the reference of MSAudioRecvPayload in the [VS CODE Installation Folder]\resources\app\extensions\typescript\node_modules\typescript\lib\lib.es6.d.ts

so it looks like VS Code by default brings the typings of typescript/node_modules along with custom typings.

I tried using excludes setting in jsconfig.json but did not work.

Appreciate if anyone can let me know how to selectively enable the custom DSL typings only.

Answer (score 0):

I figured that if we specify noLib in compilerOption, the intellisense omits the library interfaces in display,

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6",
    "noLib":true

},
 "include": [
    "src/**/*", "typings/*"
]}
```

Reference : [JSConfig options](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig#_jsconfig-options)